# Recognize tap on navigation bar title

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitapgesturerecognizer

Could someone please help me recognise a tap when a user taps on the **Title** in the **Navigation Bar**?

I would like to recognise this tap and then animate the **tableHeaderView** appearing. Possibly sliding the TableView down.

The idea being that the user can then select a quick option (from the tableViewHeader) to re-populate the TableView.

However I cannot recognise any taps. I'm using Swift.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`UINavigationBar` does not expose its internal view hierarchy.  There is no supported way to get a reference to the `UILabel` that displays the title.

You could root around in its view hierarchy “manually” (by searching through its `subviews`), but that might stop working in a future iOS release because the view hierarchy is private.

One workaround is to create a `UILabel` and set it as your view controller's `navigationItem.titleView`.  It's up to you to match the style of the default label, which may change in different versions of iOS.

That said, it's pretty easy to set up:

```
override func didMove(toParentViewController parent: UIViewController?) {
    super.didMove(toParentViewController: parent)

    if parent != nil && self.navigationItem.titleView == nil {
        initNavigationItemTitleView()
    }
}

private func initNavigationItemTitleView() {
    let titleView = UILabel()
    titleView.text = "Hello World"
    titleView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: 17)
    let width = titleView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).width
    titleView.frame = CGRect(origin:CGPoint.zero, size:CGSize(width: width, height: 500))
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

    let recognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.titleWasTapped))
    titleView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    titleView.addGestureRecognizer(recognizer)
}

@objc private func titleWasTapped() {
    NSLog("Hello, titleWasTapped!")
}
```

I'm setting the size of the label to its natural width (using `sizeThatFits:`), but I'm setting its height to 500.  The navigation bar will keep the width but shrink the height to the bar's own height.  This maximizes the area available for tapping (since the natural height of the label might be only ~22 points but the bar is 44 points high).

Comment: Perfect solution. 

I fully agree with not searching through the view hierarchy, like the other examples I found, as might not work in future.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I was almost there by myself, but didn't suspect `userInteractionEnabled`. +1.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution. On later updates of the text in the uilabel, the label itself jumps to x 0 (far left of screen) for some reason. Seems like a bug in UIKit. Anyway around? (iOS 10.1.1)

Comment: I could not reproduce the above problem 100%, however it seems to be gone for now if I do this AFTER I changed the text of said UILabel: `[self.navigationItem.titleView.superview setNeedsLayout];`. It indeed stopped the label from jumping to X 0.

Comment: That would have been my suggestion.

Comment: I just tried my app on iOS11 and the height of 500 doesn't work well: it doesn't get resized so the label may not appear or it may appear in the middle of the screen. I changed it to the nav bar height: 44.

Answer (score 39):

From the answers, we can tell there are two approaches to do this.

1. Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `titleView`. This does not seem elegant and requires you to manually set the navigation bar title font so I would not recommend it.
2. Add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the `navigationBar`. This seems pretty elegant but the problem with the posted answers that take this approach is that they all result in preventing controls within the navigation bar from working. Here is my implementation of this method that allows your controls to continue working.

---

```
// Declare gesture recognizer
var tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Instantiate gesture recognizer
    tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(self.navigationBarTapped(_:)))
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // Add gesture recognizer to the navigation bar when the view is about to appear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

    // This allows controlls in the navigation bar to continue receiving touches
    tapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

    // Remove gesture recognizer from navigation bar when view is about to disappear
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
}

// Action called when navigation bar is tapped anywhere
@objc func navigationBarTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer){

    // Make sure that a button is not tapped.
    let location = sender.location(in: self.navigationController?.navigationBar)
    let hitView = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hitTest(location, with: nil)

    guard !(hitView is UIControl) else { return }

    // Here, we know that the user wanted to tap the navigation bar and not a control inside it 
    print("Navigation bar tapped")

}
```

Comment: I didn't know about `sender.location(in` It's a smart way. I can't vote it enough.

Comment: Nice solution. I like the viewWillDisappear which removes it for child views. Nice!

Comment: This is nice but stop working as expected with iOS 16 because titleView now goes as _UINavigationBarTitleControl which is also a UIControl.

Comment: @PavelVavilov I found a workaround. You can use a recursive function to find hitView's Superview as UIControl.
if let hitView, 
            let hitObject: UIControl = UIView.retrieveUISuperviewComponent(from: hitView) {
 print("Found UIControl”) 
} else {  
print("Navigation bar tapped”) 
}

Comment: extension UIView {
    static func retrieveUISuperviewComponent<T>(from uiView: UIView) -> T? {
        var parent: T?
        if let uiParentView = uiView.superview as? T { parent = uiParentView
        } else if let uiSuperView = uiView.superview {
            parent = retrieveUISuperviewComponent(from: uiSuperView)
        }
        return parent
    }
}

Answer (score 24):

This is a solution, albeit not super elegant.  In the storyboard just place a regular UIButton over the title and attach it to an IBAction in your ViewController.  You may need to do this for each view.

Comment: This is great solution, actually, works perfect and easy to implement.

Answer (score 8):

A simple approach may be just creating the tap gesture recognizer and attaching it to your navigation bar element.

```
// on viewDidLoad
let tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(YourViewController.somethingWasTapped(_:)))
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

func somethingWasTapped(_ sth: AnyObject){
    print("Hey there")
}
```

Comment: Best way to do it.

Comment: In my case this broke the functionality of the back button after another viewcontroller was pushed onto the stack.

Comment: It will break the functionality of of other buttons in navigation bar

Comment: Please see my answer. It takes this approach but keeps the buttons in the navigation bar functional.

Comment: Million dollars answer (Y)

Answer (score 8):

Bruno's answer was 90% there for me.  One thing I noted, though, was that  UIBarButtonItem functionality for the Navigation Controller stopped working in other View Controllers, once this gesture recognizer was added to it.  To fix this, I just remove the gesture from the Navigation Controller when the view is preparing to disappear:

```
var tapGestureRecognizer : UITapGestureRecognizer!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

  tapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self, action: #selector(self.navBarTapped(_:)))

  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

  self.navigationController?.navigationBar.removeGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)

}

func navBarTapped(_ theObject: AnyObject){

  print("Hey there")

}
```

Comment: that's a much easier solution if it's primarily about tapping on the navigation bar and not just on the title in particular! It also reuses an existing UIView and doesn't require the introduction of a new view.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding `navigationItem.titleView` is a `UIView` indeed, I ended up using a `UIButton` which gives all the flexibility out-of-box.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    // Create title button
    let titleViewButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    titleViewButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
    titleViewButton.setTitle("Tap Me", for: .normal)

    // Create action listener
    titleViewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.titleViewButtonDidTap), for: .touchUpInside)

    // Set the title view with newly created button
    navigationItem.titleView = titleViewButton
}

@objc func titleViewButtonDidTap(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Title did tap")
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There is a simpler and more elegant solution using gesture recognisers (at least for iOS 9 and above).

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * titleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(titleTapped)];
[self.navigationItem.titleView addGestureRecognizer:titleTapRecognizer];
```

Then add the title tapped method:

```
-(void) titleTapped {
    // Called when title is tapped
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to define `self.navigationItem.titleView` as in the accepted answer. Default is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Zia: Your `guard !(hitView is UIControl)` solution has been working well for me while running under iOS 9 but when I run the same code in newer iOS versions it fails to see the hitView as a UIControl when the tapped barButton is disabled.

I have a number of UIBarButtonItems in my navigation bar.  When these barButtons are enabled the (hitView is UIControl) in my UITapGestureRecognizer action works correctly and the action function exits.  But if the UIBarButtonItem is disabled and the user taps on the button, the `(hitView is UIControl)` is false and the code proceeds as if the user has tapped the navigation bar.

The only way I have found to work around this problem is to obtain the UIView object for all my barButtons in viewWillAppear with:

```
button1View = button1Item.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView
```

etc...

And then in my UITapGestureRecognizer action function I test:

```
if [button1View, button2View, button3View, button4View].contains(hitView)
{
  return
}
```

This is an ugly workaround!  Any idea why (hitView is UIControl) should return false on a disabled bar button?

Comment: Update: my workaround only seems to work in iOS 9. In iOS 12 the hitView is not recognized as my barButton.  I do not have an iOS 12 development device so unable to debug this.  But I am guessing that in iOS 12 a disabled barButton is not seen as a UIControl or the returned hitView is the underlying navigationBar.

Answer (score 0):

Just put a Transparent UIButton on custom titleview.

```
let maskButton = UIButton(frame: .zero)
// ....
// your views...
// add Transparent button at last
addSubview(maskButton)
maskButton.snp.makeConstraints({
    $0.edges.equalToSuperview()
})
// listener tap event 
maskButton.addTarget(self,action:#selector(buttonClicked)....
```